qr code scanning for flutter web app (not mobile deployed yet)
i'm trying to create a custom widget/action to scan a qr code and then return the result as a String for my Flutter app. however I have not yet pursued app deployment, so am operating under web app constraints and can't use many traditional packages. i am also curious if i should be doing something like deploying the web app via terminal and Github, however it seems to me that I cannot get any changes I make in the project's base code/actions/etc in an editor like VSCode to sync with my Flutter app in the Flutter UI itself. could anyone help me figure out how to do either one of these two things? this has been stumping me for a while now so any help is so, so, appreciated. thank you so much! :)
i've tried to create a custom QR code scanning action in the Flutter UI, but because i cannot import needed dependencies and add them to my pubspec this is not working. it's also difficult since I haven't deployed to the App Store, so need some solution for a native Web app
